# Convert timestamp with offset to UTC

Tags: java, utc, java-time, java.time.instant, offsetdatetime

### Conversion

I have a timestamp with an offset (`-6`) in the following format:

```java
2019-11-30T00:01:00.000-06:00
```

and I want to convert it to an UTC timestamp, like:

```java
2019-11-30T06:01:00.000Z
```

### Attempt

I tried it the following way:

```
String text = "2019-11-30T00:01:00.000-06:00";

LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(text, DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE);

System.out.println(date.toInstant());
```

but it is not compiling:

> The method `toInstant()` is undefined for the type `LocalDate`

How am I supposed to do this correctly?

Comment: Your _date_ is not just a date, it also has time. It is also not a _local_ date/time, it has offset information. You probably intended to parse this text as `OffsetDateTime` or perhaps as `ZonedDateTime`, and then go to `Instant`.

Comment: `BASIC_ISO_DATE` will accept `20191130-0600`. As you can see, this is not the format of your string. Also `LocalDate` hasn’t got a `toInstant` method (last time I checked).

Comment: In newer Java versions `Instant.parse()` directly accepts your string. `Instant.parse(date).toString()` yields `2019-11-30T06:01:00Z`.

Comment: @Zabuzard Very nice edit! Thanks. user_che_ban, may this serve as inspiration for your next Stack Overflow questions?

Comment: Do you know for sure that you need the `.000` fraction of second when it is zero? You are asking for [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, and in ISO 8601 the fraction is optional when it is zero. So the receiver of your string probably doesn’t care. Asking because the classes of java.time (`Instant` and also `OffsetDateTime`) print ISO 8601 from their `toString` methods but include the fraction of second only if it is non-zero.

Comment: in the existing application they are setting the value like that , with `.000` , I am also following the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### tl;dr

```java
String text = "2019-11-30T00:01:00.000-06:00";
OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(text);
Instant instant = offsetDateTime.toInstant();

System.out.println(instant); // 2019-11-30T06:01:00Z

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")
  .withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);
System.out.println(formatter.format(instant)); // 2019-11-30T06:01:00.000Z
```

### Explanation

Your *date* is not just a date, it also has time. So `LocalDate` would not work. If at all, then `LocalDateTime`.

But, it is also not a **local** date/time, it has offset information. You need to use `OffsetDateTime` instead, and then go to `Instant` from there.

To actually get the desired output for your `Instant`, you also have to create a proper `DateTimeFormatter`, since the default representation does not include the millis.

Comment: Good answer. Thanks for including a good explanation.

Answer (score 4):

Slightly different approach to what Zabuzard posted due to not using an `Instant` explicitly…

You will need to

- parse the `String`,
- adjust the offset from `-06:00` to UTC and then
- get the desired `String` representation by means of a `DateTimeFormatter`

So… **tl;dr**:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // example input
    String someDateTime = "2019-11-30T00:01:00.000-06:00";
    // parse directly
    OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(someDateTime);
    // define a DateTimeFormatter for the desired output
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter
                                .ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");
    // print the parsing result using the DateTimeFormatter
    System.out.println("Origin: " 
            + odt.format(dtf));
    // adjust the offset from -06:00 to UTC
    OffsetDateTime utcOdt = odt.withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
    // print the result — again using the DateTimeFormatter
    System.out.println("UTC:    " 
            + utcOdt.format(dtf));
}
```

Output:

```
Origin: 2019-11-30T00:01:00.000-06:00
UTC:    2019-11-30T06:01:00.000Z
```

Comment: Both the posted answers are very good. I tend to prefer this solution, to me the code is a bit clearer.